# Android OpenCV Improving detection quality

Tags: java, android, opencv, geometry

Currently I am developing an app, which will detect circles from photos. I have managed to write a code for this, but it either does false negatives or false positives, if I get phone a bit away from PC screen. How can I improve the result?I mean, there are lots of apps that detect small and unclear circles.

[Update]

I'm fiddling with values in `GaussianBlur` and `HoughCircles`. Changing
`Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayMat, grayMat, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2);` to `Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayMat, grayMat, new Size(9, 9), 9, 9);` and double `param1 = 70, param2 = 72;` to `double param1 = 50, param2 = 52;` improve the result, but not enough.

```
            Mat mat = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                    CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Mat grayMat = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                    CvType.CV_8UC1);

            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);

            int colorChannels = (mat.channels() == 3) ? Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY
                    : ((mat.channels() == 4) ? Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY : 1);

            Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, grayMat, colorChannels);


            Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayMat, grayMat, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

            // accumulator value
            double dp = 1.2d;
            // minimum distance between the center coordinates of detected circles in pixels
            double minDist = 100;


            int minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 0;

            double param1 = 70, param2 = 72;


            Mat circles = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);


            Imgproc.HoughCircles(grayMat, circles,
                    Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, minDist, param1,
                    param2, minRadius, maxRadius);


            int numberOfCircles = 9;

            if (numberOfCircles > circles.cols()){ 
                numberOfCircles = circles.cols();
             }


            for (int i=0; i<numberOfCircles;  i++) {



                double[] circleCoordinates = circles.get(0, i);



                if(circleCoordinates == null){
                break;
                 }



                int x = (int) circleCoordinates[0], y = (int) circleCoordinates[1];

                Point center = new Point(x, y);
                android.graphics.Point centerC = new android.graphics.Point(x, y);

                int radius = (int) circleCoordinates[2];



                Core.circle(mat, center, radius, new Scalar(0,
                        255, 0), 4);


                Core.rectangle(mat, new Point(x - 5, y - 5),
                        new Point(x + 5, y + 5),
                        new Scalar(0, 128, 255), -1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Right now I use those A-shaped points to test the code, but I want to detect even smaller circles on the photo. 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried different sets of parameters for param1 and param2?

Comment: No. I didn't. How do you think I should try to change them. Increase param 2?

Comment: My first guess would be to decrease param2. You'll have a few more false positives, but I assume it is easier to deal with false positives than false negatives. 

Second, try decreasing param1. This increases the sensitivity of the Canny edge detector, which may be nice when you're looking to detect circles that don't stand out sharply from the background.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to play with values. Do you know how to fix the crash when there less circles then 9?

Comment: Posted an answer. Let me know if the parameter tuning works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, if you want to detect only white circles, you need to implement color detection. Not only it will greatly improve detection quality, but remove a lot of false positives and negatives. Using color detection is pretty simple, since it is already present in OpenCV. For this use `Core.inRange` function. You can find more about it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html). But probably the best thing for you would be follow [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/) tutorial. It was written in Python, but it's understandable and you need to change only few lines to get it work for android. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer! If you look into comments, you'll see that I came up with same solution to the question. Sigh, if only you replied few days earlier...

Comment: Does that mean I won't get a reward? T-T

Comment: Nah, I guess you still deserve it. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you post the workable code for android @Olelsandr Firsov.

Comment: Nope. The code is archived somewhere on my PC and it's a pain to look for it. I do remember the problem though. Poor detection is due to you setting a very specific color to detect. `inRange` allows you to include not only that exact color, but also it's shades, thus improving the detection. Just check the links for more info. The first one doesn't work, but from the looks of it, it was documentation. Go to openCV site and search for the function.

Answer (score 0):

In general, making param1 and param2 smaller will relax the threshold for recognizing circles, so there will be more false positives [detecting a circle where there is none] and fewer false negatives [not detecting a circle where there is one].

Param2 sets the circle-detection threshold. If the number is smaller, more circles in general will be detected.

Param1 sets the sensitivity threshold for the Canny edge detector. If the number is smaller, fainter circles are more likely to be detected than with a bigger number.

**As with anything in computer vision or machine learning, if it's not working reliably and you don't know why, try changing some parameters.** :-D

The crash when there are fewer than nine circles comes from hardcoding the number of circles to nine. When there are fewer than nine circles, the program tries to access beyond the bounds of the Mat array.

I don't have a system to test some OpenCV at the moment, but I can write up some code. My only caveat is that you might need `circles.rows` instead of `circles.cols`. Edit: also, circles is null if it has 0 entries.

```
int numberOfCircles = 9;
if (circles == null) numberOfCircles = 0;
else if (numberOfCircles > circles.cols) numberOfCircles = circles.cols;

for (int i=0; i<numberOfCircles;  i++) {
    double[] circleCoordinates = circles.get(0, i);
    ...
```

Comment: This code helped. Partly. Now app does not crash if I have from 1 to x circles. If the number is 0 - crash.

Comment: Ok. I've fixed crash error adding this if(circleCoordinates == null){
              break;
                  }

Comment: Try tuning the minRadius and maxRadius parameters. If you're only aiming to find the circles on the door and smaller, then you can give the circle detector that information.

Comment: Okay, I think I solved my problem - I'm implementing color detection, which will remove most, if not all, false positives. Thanks, though

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  Mat input  = new Mat();
  Mat rgb = new Mat();
  Mat output = new Mat();
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentImagePath, bitOpts);
  input = Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap);
  FeatureDetector fast = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
  List<KeyPoint> keypoints = new ArrayList<KeyPoint>();
  fast.detect(input, keypoints);
  Imgproc.cvtColor(input, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
  Features2d.drawKeypoints(rgb, keypoints, rgb);
  Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb, output, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
  Utils.matToBitmap(output, bitmap);
  //SHOW IMAGE
  mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  input.release();
  rgb.release();
  output.release();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I've got this - I implemented color detection.

Comment: @OleksandrFirsov So what's the problem ?